# CSS: How to animate widths, heights and opacity in order

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have a left bar that shows a list of links. When clicking on a collapse icon, i would like the following to happen in order:

1. The text to fade out
2. The width of the bar to reduce to a set width (animated)
3. For icons to fade in

The UI should now be a left bar with two icons, no text.

When clicking on the expand button afterwards, I would like the opposite to occur.

1. Icons to fade out
2. The width of the bar to increase to a set width (animated)
3. For the text to fade in

The UI should now be back to normal with increased width with each LI displaying it's title and description. No icon.

Below is as far as i've managed to get. I'll be performing this with a Javascript framework by toggling a class based on data, but for demonstration purposes, i have hooked up a button to toggle the menu state with jQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#button').click(function(){
    $('.container').toggleClass("toggleOn toggleOff");
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}

ul {
  list-style:none;
}

.icon {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #007cbe;
  opacity:0;
}

.text h2,
.text p {
  margin:0; padding: 0;
}

li {
  margin-bottom:20px;
}

.text {
  max-height:200px;
}


/* Transitions */
.toggleOn .text {
    overflow: hidden; 
    transition-delay:5000ms;
    max-height: 0px; 
    opacity: 0;
    transition: max-height 0ms 5000ms, opacity 4000ms 0ms;
}

.toggleOn .menu-slider {
    overflow: hidden; 
    transition-delay:5000ms;
    width: 8rem; 
    transition: width 2000ms 5000ms;
}

.toggleOff .menu-slider {
    width: 20rem;
}

.toggleOn .menu-slider {
  background:orange;
}
.toggleOff .menu-slider {
  background:pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container toggleOff">
  <div class="menu-slider">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="icon"></div>
        <div class="text">
          <h2> Title </h2>
          <p> Description </p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="icon"></div>
        <div class="text">
          <h2> Title 2 </h2>
          <p> Description 2 </p>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>  
</div>

<button id="button">Test</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#button').click(function(){
    $('.container').toggleClass("toggleOn toggleOff");
  })
})
```

```css
body,
.text h2,
.text p,
ul {
  margin:0; padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
}

.menu-slider {
  height: 100%;
}

ul {
  list-style:none;
}

li {
  padding:10px 0;
}

.icon {
  width: 0rem;
  height: 0rem;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #007cbe;
  opacity:0;
}

.text {
  max-height:200px;
}


/* Transitions */
.toggleOn .text {
  overflow: hidden; 
  max-height: 0px; 
  opacity: 0;
  transition: max-height 0ms 5000ms, opacity 4000ms 0ms;
}

.toggleOn .menu-slider {
  overflow: hidden; 
  transition-delay:5000ms;
  width: 8rem; 
  transition: width 2000ms 5000ms;
}

.toggleOn .icon {
  overflow: hidden; 
  width: 2rem; 
  height: 2rem;
  opacity: 100;
  background-color:purple;
  transition: opacity 1000ms 9000ms, width 1000ms 9000ms, height 1000ms 9000ms;
}


.toggleOff .icon {
  overflow: hidden; 
  width: 0rem; 
  height: 0rem;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 150ms 0ms, width 150ms 4000ms, height 150ms 4000ms;
}

.toggleOff .menu-slider {
  overflow: hidden; 
  width: 20rem; 
  transition: width 2000ms 6000ms;
}

.toggleOff .text {
  overflow: hidden; 
  max-height: 300px; 
  opacity: 100;
  transition: max-height 0ms 6000ms, opacity 4000ms 7000ms;
}

.toggleOn .menu-slider {
  background:orange;
}
.toggleOff .menu-slider {
  background:pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container toggleOff">
  <div class="menu-slider">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="icon"></div>
        <div class="text">
          <h2> Title </h2>
          <p> Description </p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="icon"></div>
        <div class="text">
          <h2> Title 2 </h2>
          <p> Description 2 </p>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>  
</div>

<button id="button">Test</button>
```